# Plane wave solutions to linear PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given is the linear PDE $\sum\nolimits_{j=1}^m A_{j}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_{j}} = 0$, where $A_{j}$ are matrices and $z:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is a vectorvalued function. The following set is given by $a\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that for any choice of the function $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the function $z(x) = ah(x \cdotp \xi)$ solves the PDE.
$$ \Lambda = \Biggl\{a\in \mathbb{R}^d : \exists \xi \in (\mathbb{R}^m-{0}) \; \text{with} \; \sum_{j=1}^m \xi_{j}A_{j}a=0 \Biggr\}$$

If I insert $z(x) = ah(x \cdotp \xi)$ in the PDE I get $0 = \sum\nolimits_{j=1}^m A_{j}a \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_{j}}(x \cdotp \xi) \xi_{j}$. As the solution should be independent of the choice of $h$, it must hold $A_{j}a\xi_{j}=0 \; \forall \; j \in \{1,...,m\}$. From this follows $\sum_{i=1}^m \xi_{j}A_{j}a=0$, but I need an equivalence for writing the set like that. Could someone explain why it is possible to write the set like that?